# How to set HeadlessContinuationOption in Ghidra Python preScript

Tags: python, reverse-engineering, jython-2.7, ghidra

I'm running a Ghidra python script in headless mode from the commandline specifying my script as a preScript.
e.g. `./analyzeHeadless project_path project_name -preScript pre.py -import my_exec_file`

I would like so set the HeadlessContinuationOption in that script.

The equivalent in a Java preScript will be:

```
import ghidra.app.util.headless.HeadlessScript;

public class Pre extends HeadlessScript {
  @Override
  public void run() throws Exception {
      setHeadlessContinuationOption(HeadlessContinuationOption.ABORT);
  }
}
```

However in the python there is no class to inherit from HeadlessScript (and `setHeadlessContinuationOption` in an instance method of that abstract class). I just write the script in the global scope.

I've tried to create a class similar to how the Java script is written, but nothing instantiate it. I've also tried to instantiate it and call `run` myself and call `setHeadlessContinuationOption` on that instance in `run`, but it doesn't have the desired effect (the abort option is being ignore and importing of the exec file continues).
Here's this code (that doesn't work)

```
from ghidra.app.util.headless import HeadlessScript

class Pre(HeadlessScript):
        def run(self):
                self.setHeadlessContinuationOption(self.HeadlessContinuationOption.ABORT)
Pre().run()
```

**So how can I set `setHeadlessContinuationOption(HeadlessContinuationOption.ABORT)` in a python preScript?**

Thanks.

Comment: Wanted to add a Ghidra tag but it doesn't exist and I don't have enough reputation to create it. If someone mods this question, it will be useful to have this tag.

Comment: why are you using self to access? you can access it directly - `setHeadlessContinuationOption(HeadlessContinuationOption.ABORT)`

Comment: @R4444, Thanks for commenting, however, it's not accessible directly (it's not in `globals()` - again, I'm running in headless mode).
As for why I'm using self, as I wrote, it's an example of a failed attempt, just before running out of ideas and posting here :)

Comment: Tried `HeadlessScript.setHeadlessContinuationOption(HeadlessScript.HeadlessContinuationOption.ABORT)`, but it demands two arguments. Best way is to raise an issue or question in their github. I am sure someone will help.